# Set qtreeview item to editable by context menu and automatically set it back to disabled?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a qtreeview where it's items are editable by right clicking on them and selecting edit out of the context menu. Right now I am just getting the item out of the treeview and setting it to editable, then invoking item.edit().

I cannot figure out the otherside of it though. I have to figure out how to set that item back to non editable after the edit field closes.

Ideally I would just capture a signal that fires right after the edit box closes, but I can't seem to find one.

Any Ideas?

Edit: I am using a QSortFilterProxyModel with a QStandardItemModel behind it, and QStandardItems inside. The real question is this.

Is there a signal that fires after an edit box closes for a qstandarditem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect when the editor closes then you must use the delegate's [`closeEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#closeEditor) signal.

Considering that if your model is a [`QStandardItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) then you can enable the [`Qt::ItemIsEditable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) using the [`setEditable()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setEditable) method of [`QStandardItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html).

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.treeview.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeview.customContextMenuRequested.connect(
            self.on_customContextMenuRequested
        )
        self.treeview.itemDelegate().closeEditor.connect(self._on_closeEditor)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeview)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.model)

        for i in range(4):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{i}")
            it.setEditable(False)
            self.model.appendRow(it)
            for j in range(5):
                child_it = QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{i}-{j}")
                child_it.setEditable(False)
                it.appendRow(child_it)

        self.treeview.expandAll()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWidget*")
    def _on_closeEditor(self, editor):
        p = editor.pos()
        index = self.treeview.indexAt(p)
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        it = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        it.setEditable(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested(self, pos):
        index = self.treeview.indexAt(pos)
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        edit_action = menu.addAction("&Edit")
        action = menu.exec_(self.treeview.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action == edit_action:
            it = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
            it.setEditable(True)
            self.treeview.edit(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. treeview.itemdelegate().closeEditor was exactly what I needed.